# How to Migrate wordpress blog to AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have a WordPress blog on my website www.xyz.com/blog which was working fine. Now I want to move my blog to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I have already moved my website successfully and created a separate database using AWS RDS. wp-config.php has been changed as per the AWS endpoint, as has the database name, username & password etc.

However, when I view my blog www.xyz.com/blog it just shows an empty page without showing any errors. I don't want to install WordPress separately as a new application in AWS EBS. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also move your .htaccess file?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?YourDomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog [L]
```

You'll also need to be sure that your wordpress files are in the /blog directory underneath your root folder if you want to use domain.com/blog

Also, try setting WP_DEBUG = true in wp-config.php, this will let you know if there are any script issues.